# Animate rotation node in Scenekit using CAKeyframeAnimation

Tags: swift, animation, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

in order to study ARKit and SceneKit I'm writing a simple app which should do 2 things:

1. place an airplane in a 3d world
2. animate this plane in order to make this plane fly in a circular way (I'll be happy if I can make fly this airplane in a square path).

Now, I'm stuck on the second point, animate the plane.

I tried different approaches but not successful.

First try: Animate using "sequanceAction", but as you can you can see from the following code the plane first move to X that rotate(Yaxes) and than move in Z (the animation is very ugly).

```
func animataAirplane(nodeToAnimate: SCNNode){
    let moveinx = SCNAction.move(to: SCNVector3(nodeToAnimate.position.x + 1,nodeToAnimate.position.y,nodeToAnimate.position.z), duration: 2)
    let rotateRight = SCNAction.rotate(by: deg2rad(-90), around: SCNVector3(0, 1, 0), duration: 1)
    let moveinz = SCNAction.move(to: SCNVector3(nodeToAnimate.position.x + 1,nodeToAnimate.position.y,nodeToAnimate.position.z + 1), duration: 2)
    let sequanceAction = SCNAction.sequence([moveinx, rotateRight, moveinz])
    nodeToAnimate.runAction(sequenceAction)
}
```

what I want is overly the animations, almost at the end of the moveX action start the rotation action and moveinZ, in order to give the illusion of a real plane turn.

Is that possible? I'm looking for someone point me in the right direction what I should look .

My second approach was try "CAKeyframeAnimation":

But I can't find exactly how to combine this animation:

```
func animatePlaneKey(nodeToAnimate: SCNNode){
    let pos = nodeToAnimate.position
    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    let pos1 = SCNVector3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z)
    let pos2 = SCNVector3(pos.x + 1 , pos.y, pos.z)
    let pos3 = SCNVector3(pos.x + 1 , pos.y, pos.z + 1)

    animation.values = [pos1,pos2, pos3]
    animation.keyTimes = [0,0.5,1]
    animation.calculationMode = .linear
    animation.duration = 10
    animation.repeatCount = 1
    animation.isAdditive = true
            
    let animation2 = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "rotation")
    let pos1rot = SCNVector3(nodeToAnimate.eulerAngles.x, nodeToAnimate.eulerAngles.y, nodeToAnimate.eulerAngles.z)
    let pos2rot = SCNVector3(nodeToAnimate.eulerAngles.x + Float(deg2rad(90)), nodeToAnimate.eulerAngles.y + Float(deg2rad(90)), nodeToAnimate.eulerAngles.z + Float(deg2rad(90)))
    animation2.values = [pos1rot,pos2rot]
    animation2.keyTimes = [0,1]
    animation2.duration = 2
    animation2.repeatCount = 1
    animation2.isAdditive = true
            
    nodeToAnimate.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "position")
    nodeToAnimate.addAnimation(animation2, forKey: "rotation")
}
```

Will be happy if someone can point me in the right direction in order to simulate this fly animation.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could fire a second animation on the node. i.Ex. the first animation sequence, that moves the plane from A to B to C to D and then back to A - and a second sequence that rotates the plane the way you want. you could add kind of pauses between the rotation actions (SCNAction.wait). so that it only rotates when it comes close to the corners. Then attach both Actions to your node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working version of your code:

```
func animatePlaneKey(nodeToAnimate: SCNNode) {

    let pos = nodeToAnimate.position
    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    let pos1 = SCNVector3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z)
    let pos2 = SCNVector3(pos.x + 1 , pos.y, pos.z)
    let pos3 = SCNVector3(pos.x + 1 , pos.y, pos.z + 1)

    animation.values = [pos1,pos2, pos3]
    animation.keyTimes = [0,0.5,1]
    animation.calculationMode = .linear
    animation.duration = 10
    animation.repeatCount = 1
    animation.isAdditive = true
            
    let animation2 = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "rotation")
    let pos1rot = SCNVector4(0, 0, 0, 0)
    let pos2rot = SCNVector4(0, 1, 0, CGFloat(Float.pi/2))
    animation2.values = [pos1rot, pos2rot]
    animation2.keyTimes = [0, 1]
    animation2.duration = 20
    animation2.repeatCount = 1
    animation2.isAdditive = true
            
    nodeToAnimate.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "position")
    nodeToAnimate.addAnimation(animation2, forKey: "spin around")
}
```

Comment: Does this answer mean that if you use CAKeyframeAnimation to set the rotation value, you use quaternions?

Comment: You can use `CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "rotation")` for Quaternions rotation (SCNVector4), and `CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "eulerAngles")` for Euler rotation (SCNVector3). In my answer I used Quaternions.